# Swipe in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have found a few places that use swipe and it works in all browsers, even IE8. For instance I love this web:http://www.philippebordonado.com/

(I tried things like jQuery Mobile and it does not work in old browsers like IE8)

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It looks like he is using Flexslider:  http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is using Hammer.js library for the gestures.

From the Hammer.js site ( http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ ):

Supported gestures:

Hammer supports Tap, DoubleTap, Swipe, Drag, Pinch, and Rotate gestures. Each gesture triggers useful events and eventData.

It also has a quite a large compatibility chart with windows IE8 listed.

The documented source is on github and it does a good job of explaining how it works: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js